# Differential equation application question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integration

The air in a room with volume $200m^3$ contains 0.15% carbon dioxide initially. Fresher air with only 0.05% carbon dioxide flows into the room at a rate of $2m^3/min$ and the mixed air flows out at the same rate.

a) Find the amount of carbon dioxide in the room as a function of time.
b) What is the level of carbon dioxide in the long run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y(t)$ be the amount of carbon dioxide (in $m^3$) in the room at time $t$ (in $min$).

The rate of change, $y'(t)$, of $y(t)$ is given by $y'(t) = (\textrm{rate in}) - (\textrm{rate out}) = 2 \cdot 0.05 -2 \cdot \frac{y(t)}{200} = -\frac{1}{100}(y(t) - 10)$.
This is a separable differential equation and you can rewrite it as $\frac{y'(t)}{y(t) - 10} = -\frac{1}{100}$.

You can integrate both sides with respect to $t$ to find $y(t)$.  This will involve a constant of integration $c$.  You can use $y(0) = 0.15 \cdot 200$ to find $c$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Much appreciated